# Host plain html web page in APEX 4.0

Tags: html, oracle, web-hosting, oracle-apex

I have a html/javascript web page that I need to run unmodified on APEX 4.0, I can't seem to figure out to achieve this. In older version of APEX you could put header and body html in page attributes, I can't see something similar in 4.0

Appreciate your inputs, I am sure I am missing out something very stupid.

**EDIT:**
I don't see the page attributes, I just see this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apex 4.0 still has page HTML Header and Body attributes.
[image]

You can also put pure HTML in an HTML region source.

However, it also has a new type of application called a [Websheet](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/application-express/more-websheets-154798.html) and it appears that you have created one of these, either intentionally or by accident.

Comment: Is that on Oracle XE? I don't recognise what I'm seeing in your screenshot.

Comment: Oh right, you are creating a Websheet application. Is that what you intended, or just a regular Apex application?

Comment: Right now I am trying with a websheet application, but my primary goal is to have completely custom html in the application, I don't intend to use any apex features.

Comment: I imagine you are better off using a regular Apex application then: you can create a minimal page template and put all your HTML in the header and body HTML as before.  Websheets are "simpler" in the sense of being easier for an unskilled user to build, but probably a lot less flexible in terms of content (I imagine).

Comment: I don't have a hosting platform, so I wish to use apex website for the time being.

Comment: The only feature of Apex that I will be using is Single Sign On

Comment: You mean apex.oracle.com?  That allows you to create either type of application.

Comment: Thank Tony, somehow it skipped my mind on how to create an app from scratch, with your help I now know how to do it. Thanks again. As usual, you guys are awesome.